# Ansible: how to iterate over a dictionaries

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible, ansible-2.x

Here is the output.

```
ok: [vm1.nodekite.com] => {
"containerdict": {
    "webproxy": "customer1",
    "egacustomer": "webproxy",
    "platform": "opshop-app"
}
```

}

How to pass dictionary's first key to groups using loops.

```
  - add_host:
      name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      groups: "{{ item.key }}"
    loop: "{{ containerdict }}"
```

My code throws me error

```
`"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'key'`
```

i need the output like below:

```
    "add_host": {
    "groups": [
        "webproxy"
    ],
    "host_name": "vm1.nodekite.com",
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it this way

```
- add_host:
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    groups: "{{ item.key }}"
  loop: "{{ containerdict|dict2items }}"
```

Comment: A fine solution; the other, likely more common, way is [`with_dict:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/dict.html)

Comment: Be careful! There is no such thing as "dictionary's first key". There is no guarantee which key will be first when you process a dictionary.

Comment: thank you,vladimir and mdaniel...will keep that in mind!:)